Docker image build not working for glmnet and Amazon Linux
I am creating a Dockerfile to run R workloads in Lambda based on a template from the lambdr package, which relies on an Amazon Linux base image and yum package manager. I need glmnet for one of the workloads I want to run. However, I can't get to install glmnet as it seems like there is some issue with the compilation.
This is the beginning of my Dockerfile:
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/provided:al2-x86_64

ENV R_VERSION=4.4.0

# Installs wget, git, tar, gcc and other development libraries
RUN yum -y install wget git tar gcc gcc-c++ libcurl-devel openssl-devel libxml2-devel

# Install EPEL
RUN yum -y install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm \
  # Install specific R version
  && wget https://cdn.rstudio.com/r/centos-7/pkgs/R-${R_VERSION}-1-1.x86_64.rpm \
  && yum -y install R-${R_VERSION}-1-1.x86_64.rpm \
  && rm R-${R_VERSION}-1-1.x86_64.rpm
    
# Install AWS CLI
RUN curl "https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64.zip" -o "awscliv2.zip" \
    && unzip awscliv2.zip \
    && ./aws/install

# Accept AWS credentials as build arguments
ARG AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
ARG AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY

# Set AWS credentials in the environment
ENV AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}
ENV AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}


ENV PATH="${PATH}:/opt/R/${R_VERSION}/bin/"

# Creates a configuration file for R to set the C++ compiler.
RUN mkdir -p /root/.R && echo "CXX17 = g++" >> /root/.R/Makevars

RUN Rscript -e "install.packages('glmnet',  \
                                 INSTALL_opts =c('--no-docs', '--no-data',\
                                                  '--no-help', '--no-demo'),\
                                 repos = 'https://packagemanager.rstudio.com/all/__linux__/centos7/latest')"

I then call
docker build --build-arg AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID={AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}--build-arg AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY={AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY} -t r-on-lambda .

Which outputs this at the end:
#11 107.7 /usr/bin/ld: RcppExports.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.bss' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
#11 107.7 /usr/bin/ld: elnet_exp.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.bss' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
#11 107.7 /usr/bin/ld: glmnet_init.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.data' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
#11 107.7 /usr/bin/ld: internal.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
#11 107.7 /usr/bin/ld: pb_exp.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.bss' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
#11 107.7 /usr/bin/ld: wls_exp.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.bss' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
#11 107.7 /usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Nonrepresentable section on output
#11 107.7 collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
#11 107.7 make: *** [glmnet.so] Error 1
#11 107.7 ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘glmnet’
#11 107.7 * removing ‘/opt/R/4.4.0/lib/R/library/glmnet’
#11 107.8 
#11 107.8 The downloaded source packages are in
#11 107.8   ‘/tmp/Rtmp7LKwru/downloaded_packages’
#11 107.8 Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library'
#11 107.8 Making 'packages.html' ... done
#11 107.8 Warning message:
#11 107.8 In install.packages("glmnet", INSTALL_opts = c("--no-docs", "--no-data",  :
#11 107.8   installation of package ‘glmnet’ had non-zero exit status
#11 DONE 107.9s

What is the reason for glmnet not being installed if I have gcc and gcc-c++ installed? In the log I have seen that all the dependencies (foreach, iterators, Rcpp, RcppEigen, shape) do get installed properly. How can I solve this?

The compiler, while present, is likely too anicent on that (not very developer friendly) distribution. CentOS and alike have (had?) something called devtoolset, you likely need it on AML

Actually, per your error log it is worse: recompile with -fPIC That means R is passing down bad compilation options to the package.  Neither of these is a problem with the Rcpp sources, it is with how Rcpp is being install on AML.

I've discovered you can add the -fPIC flag into the CXX17 required by glmnet:
Modifying this:
RUN mkdir -p /root/.R && echo "CXX17 = g++" >> /root/.R/Makevars

For that:
RUN mkdir -p /root/.R && \
    echo "CXX17 = g++ -fPIC" >> /root/.R/Makevars && \
    echo "CXX17FLAGS = -O3 -mtune=native -march=native -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-unused-function" >> /root/.R/Makevars

